# How to convert cents to dollars for all drop down values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a field named price_in_cents for materials table.
I want to display all the values of price_in_cents as dollars in drop down.

Here is the code:

```
  <%= select_tag 'price_in_cents', "<option value='blank'>(empty)</option>"+options_for_select(Material.pluck(:price_in_cents).compact.uniq),include_blank: true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Actually `price_in_dollars =  self.price_in_cents/(100*100).to_d`

For example price 10200 has to be displayed as 1.02.

How to write or mention the values as price_in_cents/(100*100).to_d in drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
 <%= select_tag 'price_in_cents', "<option value='blank'>(empty)</option>"+options_for_select(Material.pluck('price_in_cents/(100*100)').compact.uniq),include_blank: true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Here, performing operation while fetching record value. If you want to convert it into integer then you can write it as:

```
Material.pluck('CAST(price_in_cents/(100.0*100.0) as decimal)').compact.uniq
```

I have given example of postgresql

Comment: And also I need to convert into decimals. For example price **10200** has to be displayed as **1.02**.

Comment: Try this Material.pluck('CAST(price_in_cents/(100.0*100.0) as decimal)').compact.uniq

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to keep this conversion logic out of your views-- this sounds like a situation where the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) would be appropriate and would recommend looking into a gem like [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper). You could add a `price_in_dollars` method to your `MaterialsDecorator` and use a decorated `@materials` in your view.

Or if you are strictly looking for an array of these values, a class method such as `Material.prices_in_dollars` might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with money, I suggest you use something like [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails), it will add the necessary readers and writers for you to access the money value in dollars and save you some rounding headaches.